# Android toolbar gets hidden when I select a tab in a coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a TabLayout with 4 tabs inside a Coordinator Layout and everytime I select the 4th tab, the toolbar gets hidden. That doesn't happen with the other tabs though. Similar issue occurs when I select an item from a dropdown menu inside the 3rd tab.

How can I avoid that and allow the toolbar to get hidden only if the user scrolls up (which is the default one)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/activity_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/text_hint"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.Fragments.FabVerticalMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity.Main2Activity">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">     
    <!-- Your scrolling content -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```